# How to use parser on multiple time objects

Tags: python, python-dateutil

I have an list:

```
list = ['2022-06-01', '2022-02-02']
```

Now am using parser to convert this to python date object. like this,

```
from dateutil import parser

def to_date(value):
    for data in value:
        return parser.parse(data)
```

Above one gives just one output, but i need the output for both the times and also need to convert that to an string like this:

```
From : June 1, 2022 | To: Feb. 28, 2022
```

Is that possible with parser ?

Comment: What is `parser`? Are you aware that `return` exits the function? Do you know how to do a list comprehension or something similar, like `[parser.parse(s) for s in value]`?

Comment: Sorry am an newbie, parser is from dateutil

Comment: I would recommend using `datetime.strptime` and `strftime`. They are standard and most experienced python programmers will be familiar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only get one value back from your `to_date` function because you exit the function in the first loop iteration. You need to introduce an list storing your parsed dates temporary:

```py
from dateutil import parser

def to_date(date_list):
    parsed_date_list = []
    for date in date_list:
        parsed_date_list.append(parser.parse(date))
    return parsed_date_list

date_list = ['2022-06-01', '2022-02-02']
res = to_date(date_list)
```

---

Or using a list comprehension to keep your code more concise:

```py
from dateutil import parser

def to_date(date_list):
    return [parser.parse(date) for date in date_list]

date_list = ['2022-06-01', '2022-02-02']
res = to_date(date_list)
```

---

And to format your string, simply use the [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) function as pointed out by kpie
in his comment:

```py
# res = to_date(date_list)

date_format = "%b %d, %Y"
print(f"From: {res[0].strftime(date_format)} | To: {res[1].strftime(date_format)}")
```

---

**Do not use `list` as a variable name.** [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) is a data structure and therefore already in use by the class `list`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard `datetime` library to perform the parsing.
`datetime.datetime.strptime` allows you to convert a datetime string to a datetime object.
`datetime.datetime.strftime` allows you to convert a datetime object to the desired string.

```
dt_from, dt_to = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d") for x in dt_list]
dt_str = f"From : {datetime.datetime.strftime('%b %d,%Y', dt_from)} | To: {datetime.datetime.strftime('%b %d,%Y', dt_to)}"]
```